# Wortstellung im Nebensatz -- eine Ausnahme?

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause

Sofern ich weiß ist die Reihenfolge im Nebensatz immer **Bindewort - Subjekt - andere Satzteile - Prädikat**.
Z.B.: *"Ich weiß, dass du gestern mit dem Auto gefahren bist."* In diesem Nebensatz ist *"dass"* das Bindeword, *"du"* das Subjekt, *"gestern"* und *"mit dem Auto"* die anderen Satzteile, *"gefahren bist"* das Prädikat.

Ich habe jedoch ein Gegenbeispiel gefunden: *"Ich bin froh, weil heute die Sonne scheint."* (Statt *"Ich bin froh, weil die Sonne heute scheint."* -- *"weil"*: Bindewort, *"die Sonne"*: Subjekt, *"heute"*: andere Satzteile, *"scheint"*: Prädikat)
Für die erste, "unregelmäßige" Variante, gibt es [ungefähr 2000 Treffer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22weil%20heute%20die%20Sonne%20scheint%22) im Google, während für die zweite "regelmäßige" nur [fast 1000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22weil%20die%20sonne%20heute%20scheint%22), also halb so viel. Die erste Variante wird also (anscheinend) häufiger verwendet.

Ich habe dazu folgende Fragen:

- Ist die erste Variante auch grammatisch korrekt? Wenn sie korrekt ist, dann warum?
- Wenn sie nicht korrekt ist, ist es wahr, dass sie trotzdem häufiger verwendet wird als die zweite, "richtige" Variante?
- Gibt es ähnliche Beispiele für Nebensätze, in denen die Wortstellung oft nicht der "Bindewort - Subjekt - andere Satzteile - Prädikat"-Regel folgt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nein, auch vor dem Subjekt können im Nebensatz Satzteile stehen. Nur die Reihenfolge Subjekt–Objekte ist vorgegeben.

> Er erkannte, dass im Gegensatz zu seiner Vorstellung **die Regeln** zur Nebensatzbildung doch nicht so einfach sind.

Normalerweise stehen vor dem Subjekt adverbiale Bestimmungen. Die kann man zwar auch hinter das Subjekt stellen, dadurch verschiebt sich aber die Betonung:

> Ich bin froh, weil heute **die Sonne** scheint. *(neutral)*
>
> Ich bin froh, weil **die Sonne** heute scheint. *(und nicht etwa morgen!)*
>
> Ich weiß, dass **du** gestern mit dem Auto gefahren bist. *(neutral)*
>
> Ich weiß, dass gestern **du** mit dem Auto gefahren bist. *(und nicht etwa Lisa!)*

Der Satzteil direkt hinter dem Bindewort ist am wenigsten betont, und die Aussprache sollte dem folgen.

Comment: *Er erkannte, dass im Gegensatz zu seiner Vorstellung die Regeln zur Nebensatzbildung doch nicht so einfach sind.* ... und eine ganze Welt stürzte in ihm zusammen :D

Comment: @Attilio Nicht das die deutsche Sprache keinen Regeln folgen würde, aber in der Praxis sind oft viele Ausdrucksweisen möglich, und die Präferenz ist unklar, oder sehr subtil im Zusammenhang mit dem Kontext. Das ist der Grund, warum ich (als deutscher Muttersprachler) die englische Sprache so liebe. Zumindest an der Oberfläche ist sie um so Vieles einfacher und klarer.

Answer (score 3):

Beide Varianten sind grammatisch korrekt.

Nebensätze unterscheiden sich dadurch von Hauptsätzen, dass das konjugierte Verb (und nicht das ganze Prädikat) nicht an der 2. Position steht, sondern an der letzten. Für den restlichen Satzbau gelten dann dieselben Regeln wie für Hauptsätze.

Die Frage welche der beiden Varianten

> ..., weil heute die Sonne scheint.
>   ..., weil die Sonne heute scheint.

richtig ist, ist letztendlich also nicht weiter als die Frage, welcher der beiden folgenden Hauptsätze richtig ist:

> Heute scheint die Sonne.
>   Die Sonne scheint heute.

Die Antwort, sowohl für die Hauptsätze, als auch für die Nebensätze lautet: Beide sind richtig.

Im Vorfeld (im Hauptsatz: Die Position vor dem konjugierten Verb) kann nicht nur das Subjekt stehen, sondern so gut wie jedes Satzglied außer dem Verb. Daher kann auch in einem Nebensatz direkt nach dem Bindewort alles mögliche (außer dem Verb) kommen.

Comment: Im Nebensatz kommt die Reihenfolge Objekt(e)–Subjekt nicht vor.